# network solutions SMTP mail configuration through nodemailer

Tags: server, openssl, smtp, nodemailer

when i am using following mailer config:

```
options = {
     host: 'smtp.XXXX.com',
     port: 2525,
    secure: false,
    ignoreTLS: true,
    authMethods: ['PLAIN', 'LOGIN', 'XOAUTH2'],
    auth: { 
        user: 'no_reply@XXXX.com', 
        pass: 'XXXXX' 
},
```

it returns an error i.e.

[image]

and when i use following configurations:

```
options = {
        host: 'smtp.XXXX.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        ignoreTLS: true,
        authMethods: ['PLAIN', 'LOGIN', 'XOAUTH2'],
        auth: { 
            user: 'no_reply@XXXX.com', 
            pass: 'XXXXX' 
        },  
    };
```

it gives the error : ECONNREFUSED with error code ECONNECTION
i dont know what port and configurations should i use for network solutions SMTP .

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using NodeJS v0.9.2 or later, then you will find that the Node is doing default certificate validation for TLS and HTTPS.

Here is the [release note](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.9.2/):

> tls, https: validate server certificate by default (Ben Noordhuis)

Most probably this is the main cause of the issue you faced.

You can avoid this issue by simply adding this line before making the call:

```
rejectUnauthorized: false
```

But this can have a serious security implication. Even if the data is encrypted, because of this bypass verification rule, a middleman can actually steal your data. The data you will be sending might not be getting landed to the original recipient server instead, it might be getting diverted to a hacker's server.

This is a quick fix but not the recommended one because of the above reason.

Ideally, you should verify the recipient server by making sure the certificate is signed by a trusted CA.

You might need to debug this further with the smtp provider to understand the gap in the validation. Each certificate has a "Subject" and the subject has a "Common Name". And there can be multiple "subjectAltNames" associated with the same.
During the validation, Node actually checks the endpoint and tries to match this with Common Name or one of the subjectAltNames. If there is a mismatch it throws the error like the once you got:
Hostname/ip doesn't match certificate's altnames

Most probably, PORT is not the problem. Certificate validation is the problem.

Hope this addresses the problem.